# Python3: read from a file and sort the values

Tags: python, file, sorting, python-3.x

I have a txt file that contains data in the following fashion:

```
13
56
9
32
99
74
2
```

each value in a different file. I created three function:

the first one is to swap the values

```python
def swap(lst,x,y):
    temp = lst[x]
    lst[x] = lst[y]
    lst[y] = temp
```

and the second function is to sort the values:

```python
def selection_sort(lst):
    for x in range(0,len(lst)-1):
        print(lst)
        swap(lst,x,findMinFrom(lst[x:])+ x)
```

the third function is to find the minimum value from the list:

```python
def findMinFrom(lst):
    minIndex = -1
    for m in range(0,len(lst)):
        if minIndex == -1:
            minIndex = m
        elif lst[m] < lst[minIndex]:
            minIndex = m
    return minIndex
```

Now, how can I read from the file that contains the numbers and print them sorted?

Thanks in advance!

---

I used:

```
def main():
    f = []
    filename = input("Enter the file name: ")
    for line in open(filename):
        for eachElement in line:
            f += eachElement
    print(f)
    selectionSort(f)
    print(f)
main()
```

but still not working! any help?

Comment: Please read and apply the help->tour when you ost here. It states "There is no chit-chat" and despite that your post contains "Thanks in advance"

Comment: Your swap function has a superfluous `temp` variable and its body can be written in a single line; `lst[x], lst[y] = lst[y], lst[x]`, why make it so complicated as you do?

Comment: Anthon, I know about this line but it's not recommended as it is only existing in python, so it's actually a bad practice for me as a programmer.

Comment: Where do have that misinformation from? I used parallel assignment in Occam2  before Python was even created. And [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_%28computer_science%29#Parallel_assignment) lists 10 programming languages that can do that by name, in a non-exhaustive list.

Answer (score 3):

Good programmers don't reinvent the wheel and use sorting routines that are standard in most modern languages. You can do:

```
with open('input.txt') as fp:
    for line in sorted(fp):
        print(line, end='')
```

to print the lines sorted alphabetically (as strings). And

```
with open('input.txt') as fp:
    for val in sorted(map(int, fp)):
        print(val)
```

to sort numerically.

Comment: Monica, I can't use any build-in python sort function for this assignment. The idea is to create a function to do so, and I made one. now how can I sort the numbers in a file using my sorting function?

Comment: @r4b: there are two **independent** tasks: read numbers from a file, sort the numbers. Solve one problem at a time (divide-and-conquer). If you want to know how to read numbers from a file; forget about the sorting for a moment and learn how to read numbers. Your `selection_sort()` doesn't look like it sorts anything; to fix it, forget about reading numbers from a file and learn how to sort a list of integers instead. Once you've done the independent tasks; you could combine them (sometimes it may simplify things or allow to make the code more efficient but you can ignore it for now)

Comment: My selection_sort() does sort and I test it myself!

Answer (score 0):

To read all the lines in a file:

```
f = open('test.txt')
your_listname = list(f)
```

To sort and print

```
selection_sort(output_listname)
print(output_listname)
```

You may need to strip newline characters before sorting/printing

```
stripped_listname=[]
for i in your_listname:
    i = i.strip('\n')
    stripped_listname.append(i)
```

You probably also want to take the print statement out of your sort function so it doesn't print the list many times while sorting it.

Comment: Knells, should I do that in the main function? and I also used the input function so the user choose the file they want, so : f = input("Name of the file: ")

Comment: I you only need to do it once, the main function is perfectly fine. Don't put it in any o the functions you posted.
f = open(input("Name of the file: ")) will get data from a file with input filename.